# GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener#onDoubleTap(MotionEvent) not getting called when double clicking in simulator

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an activity intercepting touch events via the onTouchEvent method and I am using the gesture detector class to detect common movements. I have followed the Android Developer API but my SimpleGestureListener.onDoubleTap method never gets called despite double clicking.

In my activity definition I have:

```
protected final GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener handler =
        new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            final String DEBUG_STR = "Gestures";
            @Override
            public boolean onDown(MotionEvent event)
            {
                Log.i(DEBUG_STR, "onDown");
                childView.setText("onDown");
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent event)
            {
                Log.i(DEBUG_STR, "onDoubleTap");
                childView.setText("onDoubleTap");
                return true;
            }

            public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e) {
                Log.i(DEBUG_STR, "onDoubleTap");
                childView.setText("onDoubleTap");
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onFling(MotionEvent begin, MotionEvent end, float velocityX,
                                   float velocityY)
            {
                Log.i(DEBUG_STR, "onFling");
                childView.setText("onFling");
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent event)
            {
                Log.i(DEBUG_STR, "onSingleTapConfirmed");
                childView.setText("onSingleTapConfirmed");
                return true;
            }
        };

protected GestureDetector detector;
```

In my onCreate Method I initialize the gesture detector:

```
detector = new GestureDetector(this, handler);
```

And finally my onTouchEvent method:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    detector.onTouchEvent(event);
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

When I run this activity in the simulator I get everything but the double tap registering. I've tried double clicking my mouse in the activity screen on a Nexus 5 emulated device but the double tap never seems to be printed in the log or on the screen.

I'm not sure whats going wrong here. I can't see anything obviously wrong with my code as it compiles and registers fling and single tap movements. Just no double taps.